# LESS Variable plus an RGBa?

Tags: css, less

I'm terribly sorry if this is a stupid question.
I'm working on a site that will be used by clients, and need to be used everywhere. We're trying to restyle the navbar form fields, and I'm stuck.

So currently I have

```
input-foo:    lighten(@color, 27.3%);
```

And instead of this, I'd like to lighten the `@color` using the `rgba(255,255,255,27.3)`, but I can't find any answers on how to do this. I'm new to LESS and have worked primarily in CSS, and I'm switching to LESS at the moment. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, semantically "lightening a color by another color" may nean too many different things, so it would be more helpful if you specify what color value you expect as the result of such "lightening" (additionally note that `27.3%` in `lighten` and in `rgba` also means drastically different things). Either way I guess maybe something like [one](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-blending-screen) of [those functions](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-blending) is what you have in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [`mix()` function](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-mix), which combines two colors:

```
input-foo:    mix(@color, rgba(255,255,255,27.3),);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `red()`, `green()`, and `blue()` functions to get the individual RGB values for a color.

In your case, this would make:

```
rgba(red(@color), green(@color), blue(@color), 0.273);
```

Comment: Actually, you can write `rgba(@color, 0.273)`.  But that's not what he's asking for.